# I removed and reinstalled isc-dhcp-common and dependents and now I have lost wireless

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I was having problems updating my system which I tracked down to a 'half installed' isc-dhcp-common package. This was the output from Synaptic.

So I ran sudo apt-get install --reinstall isc-dhcp-common This allowed me to completely remove all four packages using Synaptic. Then I marked them for reinstallation and applied. This ran without error.

I rebooted and upon login found I didn't have wifi or nmcli or any hint of network connectivity. I assumed it'd be ok given the reinstall, but alas I messed up.

I'm hoping someone can help me out without me having to fully reinstall the OS.

Yes I know... I'm pretty new to Ubuntu. I'd be happy to hear all suggestions of how to prevent events like this occurring in the future, as well as resources for working through errors in the future.

When I try sudo lshww -C network I found out that my wifi and eth are both DISABLED. Another thing is that nmcli can no longer be accessed. I presume it is not install anymore.

Thank you in advance. Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by first running

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Of course, this failed to run but it did produce the files which it was looking for. I then found these .deb files and downloaded them (using my functional windows boot) to a usb.

These were then added to the var/cache/apt/archive/ folder and then running sudo apt-get install worked as it could find the files. Lastly, reboot.

I then had to reconfigure using:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

This fixed the problem and I am back to normal *I think*.